# How to fix a memory leak?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am trying to figure out a way to fix a memory leak in my AIR for Android application.

The issue seems to originate from the fact that I am loading external, locally stored SWF and mp4 files into my stage and playing them, one after another. It appears that the application is not removing the files from memory and as it reads the file from the local directory each time it is played, the app keeps pushing them into memory and it fills up.

I have tried setting the child SWF/mp4 movieclip to NULL after removing it from the stage (as suggested by various online sources) but that does not seem to work.

Then I tried using `System.gc();` just before a clip is to be played (so, play clip A, clips A finishes, run garbage collection, clip B plays) but again, it didn't seem to do anything.

So, I am trying to think of a way to stop this memory leak.

My idea is to add each movieclip to an array and then loop through that. I assume this may work because if the clips are stored in an array, I am not re-reading them from the local directory and therefore should not get re-added to memory. Is this a safe assumption?

Are there other ways to combat this type of memory leak?

Lastly, how likely is it that this memory leak is the cause of my app closing itself after about an hour, when stress testing it on an Android device? (no error messages pop up, the app just closes, without warning)

Comment: Which class do you use to play video files?

Comment: Note that even connected event listeners can prent objects from being garbage collected. Consider the last parameter in `addEventListener` or using `removeEventListener` read more about this issue here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener()

Comment: You may also try to force Flash collecting the garbage by creating the empty  `BitmapData` and then call `bitmapData.dispose()` method.

Comment: Anton - to play the mp4 video files, I am using NetStream and reading the local file with FileStream. Works really well and plays the videos perfectly. Just gotta figure out how to patch this darn leak! Will try the BitmapData hack

Comment: Just to add, I am also removing the event listener attached to the file being played, just before setting it to null. I tried the weak reference thing too, didn't seem to help and in some cases it broke the app.

Comment: it broke the app because the are no `strong` references, and the objects are removed during GC. May be it is the right way, but some explicit recource link table is required to maintain the desired links.

Comment: Tried the bitmap data hack, think I'm using it correctly. just before playing a file, i created a new BitmapData object and then used the dispose() method. The app crashed when it moved from playing a SWF file to the mp4 file. Odd...

Comment: Looks really odd, to clarify this issue consider using Flash Builder Profiler to see objects in the memory.

Comment: Can I use Flash Builder Profiler when the app was made fully in Flash CS6?

Comment: Try creating the Flash Professional project, point out the fla file and then compilation should work. After that try running the profiler.

Comment: How are you loading the SWF? Using a `Loader`? Have you tried Loader's [unloadAndStop()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#unloadAndStop()) method?